# EXCEL duplicate values - Incorrect highlighting

Tags: excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

in an Excel spreadsheet, I have the following values in a column. When I apply the "duplicate values" function, the following values are highlighted incorrectly (cells marked here in bold).

| Product Numer |
| --- |
| **31570010000000009213** |
| **31570010000000041126** |
| **31570010000000043842** |
| 31570010000000101363 |
| 31570020000000000274 |
| **95980020140005167173** |
| **95980020140005198310** |
| **95980020140005273582** |
| **95980020140005273776** |
| **95980020140005273873** |
| 95980020140005388333 |
| 95980020140005400000 |
| **95980020140005728027** |
| **95980020140005728221** |
| **95980020140005728415** |
| 95980020140005934443 |
| 097900BEMQ0000006410 |
| 097900BGMG0000058204 |

But these values are not duplicates! - I have already tried to define the column as "text". But this does not help either. All the highlighting looks very random, without logic. Why are they displayed as duplicates in EXCEL and how can I fix this?

Comment: What duplicate values function are you referring to?

Comment: This does not appear randomly at all, in fact the difference in these values is only made after the 15th digit.

Excel treats these as numbers despite it being text in the "duplicates values" conditional function. It treats all digits after the 15th digit as a zero essentially making the bold values equal. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/last-digits-changed-to-zeros) link. This 15-digit precision phenomenon Excel is working with is also known as "Floating Point Precision".

Comment: Thanks, I see it. I've created a new column with `=RIGHT(...,15)` and marked them duplicate. Now I see the duplicate values.